# Creating a large directed network using NetworkX and check for weak connectivity

Tags: python, networkx

I am trying to create a directed network with more than 5000 nodes. The edges between the nodes are based on the difference in a certain value assigned to each node; if the difference in values between node pairs is less than a threshold, there is an edge. I generate an adjacency matrix and want to check if the directed graph is weakly connected, and also compute Page rank. Currently, I use the code below to generate the graph and it takes me 78s and occupies nearly 7GB memory. I want to know if there is a more efficient (time and memory) way of constructing and evaluating large networks in Python.

```
%reset -f
!pip install faiss-gpu
import faiss
import numpy as np
import torch
import random
import networkx as nx
import time
device='cuda'
res = faiss.StandardGpuResources()
start=time.time()
# Total Nodes
N = 5000
# Mean
mu = 0.5*np.pi
# Variance
var = np.pi/18
# Maximum degree of each node
max_degree = 1000
# Threshold
value_thres = np.pi/6
# Placeholders
Values = torch.zeros((N,1),dtype=torch.double,device='cuda')
Matrixs = torch.zeros((2,N,max_degree),dtype=torch.double,device='cuda')
Adj_Matrix = torch.zeros((N,N),dtype=torch.long,device='cuda')
#Generate a directed network with N nodes whose connectivity is based on values
start_network=time.time()
Values[:,0] = torch.normal(mu,var,(N,))
# Find neighbors upto max_degree
# Pytorch to numpy
Current = np.float32(Values[:,0].cpu().detach().numpy())
index_flat = faiss.IndexFlatL2(Current[:,None].shape[1])
gpu_index_flat = faiss.index_cpu_to_gpu(res, 0, index_flat)
gpu_index_flat.add(Current[:,None])
m, n = gpu_index_flat.search(Current[:,None], max_degree)
# Indices of possible neighbors
Matrixs[1] = torch.from_numpy(n).long()
# Value Separation 
Matrixs[0] = torch.squeeze(torch.cdist(Values[:,0][:,None][:,None],Values[:,0][:,None][Matrixs[1].long()],p=2))<value_thres
# Construct Adjacency Matrix
Adj_Matrix[Matrixs[1].long()] = 1
Adj_Matrix-=torch.eye(N,dtype=torch.long,device='cuda')
G = nx.from_numpy_matrix(Adj_Matrix.cpu().detach().numpy())
end=time.time()
print('Network Creation Time',end-start_network)
print('Total Time',end-start-start_network)
```

Answer (score 0):

From the snippet in the question, it's hard to isolate the time/memory of networkx (I don't have 'cuda' on my machine, so unable to replicate). However, the following code runs for about 36 seconds:

```py
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np

A = np.random.randint(2, size=(5000, 5000))
G = nx.from_numpy_matrix(A)  # about 36 seconds
```

There could be scope for generating a faster algorithm by writing a custom low-level graph constructor, but it's unlikely that it will have memory advantages.